# Use $(SolutionDir) in Debug Start Action

Tags: visual-studio

I wanted to use the `$(SolutionDir)` macro in my C# project on `Properties->Debug` and then `Start action` in `Start external program`:

[image]

But I get the error message:

[image]

I am sure the Path would be valid, if the `$(SolutionDir)` macro gets translated. If I use the absolute Path it works also.
Any suggestions or smaller work arounds to solve this problem?

Maybe someone wants to ask, why I want to solve this? Because I have multiple releases of one project at different folders. If I change the release folder (open another solution) I have to manually change the external program. It would be nice, if I could make the path to the external program dependent on the current opened solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because of that $(...) the round bracket

change it to ${...} the curly bracket

visual studio file system does't work using () it by default using {}